# Debugger is choppy with Guard/Spork/Testunit

Tags: testunit, spork, guard, ruby-debug

I am using ruby 1.9.2p318, rails 3.1.3, and the following gems:

```
gem 'debugger'
gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
gem 'spork-testunit'
gem 'guard-spork'
```

When I just use spork in the terminal and run a test that includes a "debugger" line, everything works fine, and I can access the debugger prompt in the same tab from which spork was launched.

But, when I launch spork using `bundle exec guard`, the debugger is choppy. It's like there is no memory available. The window is at times unresponsive to the keyboard and won't respond to paste. My guardfile  includes the following for spork:

```
guard 'spork',  :test_unit_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
    :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, 
    :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end
```

Has anyone had the same experience or know how to resolve this? Thanks!